# How to create new folder in Files/Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

When there is no whitespace inside the listing window, is there a button I can click, or where can I right click to "Create New Folder".

Even in grid view, I have to resize the window to misalign the items to create whitespace so I can right click and find the "Create New Folder".

Am I missing a button? Right now, I just open Guake and do it from a terminal then come back to the Files app.

Screenshot of what I'm seeing
[image: Screenshot of what I'm seeing]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was an [issue in previous nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154110/how-to-enable-open-terminal-here-from-nautilus-when-in-list-not-tiled-mode) where indeed you could not anymore use the mouse to create a new folder when there was no empty space in the  pane. That now has been addressed by a more functional "breadcrumb". Besides, there are several other options.

- *Only mouse*: Click or right-click the current folder to see a "New Folder..." menu item. You see a downwards pointing arrow, hinting to that you can expect a menu dropping down there.

  [image: Breadcrumb menu dropdown]
- *Only mouse*: Click the "Hamburger menu", then the rightmost icon in the top bar, which stands for "New Folder".

  [image: New foler icon]

Alternative ways to access the option involve the keyboard:

- *Mouse or mouse and keyboard*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> revels the right-click menu that you otherwise also can obtain by right-clicking an empty space in the folder. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> followed by pressing <kbd>f</kbd> is a keyboard-only way.
- *Only keyboard*: The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> immediatelly lets you create a new folder only with the keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

I agree it's slightly annoying. I think your only options are to use the awkward 3-key keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) or click on the icon with three horizontal lines at top-right and then click on the new folder icon on the resulting popup window (also top-right).

Comment: Thank you!  The new folder icon hiding in that pop out menu is what tricked me.  It is a bit odd that the new folder icon, left to right, is AFTER new window and new tab...let alone the fact that I don't feel new folder should be grouped with those two actions anyway.

I'll accept this answer when the site allows me to in a few minutes.