# Ubuntu - Open terminal locally through shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I recently bought a new keyboard with macro keys. Unfortunately, the manufacture has proprietary software that only runs on Windows.

I have been doing some workarounds to use the macro-keys by first creating custom keyboard shortcuts and them use them in the macro-keys.

Currently, I am trying to create a shortcut to open a local terminal in a folder and lunch visual code.

In ubuntu, a local terminal can be opened by doing:

```
right click + E

Shift + F10 + E
```

I would like to know if this is possible through a command line:
with something like:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory= something to be defined --LocationOfVisualStudioLuncher
```

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

For me in Ubuntu 20.10, a

`cd <your folder> && gnome-terminal`

will open a terminal in `<your folder>`.

To spawn a terminal and your custom application, you can launch to background as in

`cd <your folder> && gnome-terminal & your_application &`

Comment: This way, I have to specify the folder, no?
Since I want to create a shortcut, it should know what folder it is on. what does it do when I press `shift + F10 + E`. How does Ubuntu know the folder?

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question then. You may want to clarify and more quickly come to the point, unless your macro keyboard is critical in this question.

Comment: It appears indeed as if SLS also did not understand what you actually want. If the question is to access the "Open in terminal" right-click menu option through a hotkey, then look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154110/how-to-enable-open-terminal-here-from-nautilus-when-in-list-not-tiled-mode/1154118#1154118. Unfortunatelly, assigning a shortcut does not anymore work in 20.10. You can of course open additional applications through the nautilus script.

Comment: Look also here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194329/keyboard-shortcut-to-create-a-new-empty-file-on-ubuntu-18-04/1194547#1194547 (end of answer) where you can assign hotkeys to nautilus script menu items. Failing the option to bind a single hotkey, the keyboard combination Shift+F10 s <your letter> is the next best thing to quickly trigger an action. Unfortunatelly, that only works when a file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by executing something like this in one line:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory ~/GIT --title "code terminal" && gnome-terminal -- code
```

for convenience add this to your ~/.bashrc file so that you have direct access to a shortcut command "gt":

```
alias gt='gnome-terminal --working-directory ~/GIT --title "code terminal" && gnome-terminal -- code'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. What is GIT?

Comment: Sorry that did not work for you. GIT is just a folder name "working directory",  "~/" is short hand for the users home directory. So you would get an error if that folder did not exist. Please try again, but substitute ~/GIT with the folder you want instead. If you tell me more precisely what you want to do I can help better. What was the error you got?